# Slightly bent rim

Tags: maintenance, wheels

I have seen that my rear wheel rim is slightly bent. Can I use it for a week and take to the technician Sunday? Will there be any problem if I ride it for a week?

[image]

Comment: If the tire is staying on, the tire isn't rubbing against the frame, and the ride is not impossibly bumpy then you should be able to ride the bike.  However, if the "bend" is due to a broken spoke (can't tell from your picture) then you do risk having more spokes fail, and sooner or later the wheel will become unrideable.  But if the problem is a simple dinged rim then there should be no major increase in failure risk.

Answer (score 3):

The bend can't be too bad because it's not visible in the picture.

If the bend is lateral (side to side) and the rim is not hitting the brake pads too hard, it's fine.

If the bend is radial, that might indicate that you hit something pretty hard. If you can't feel it when you are riding it's probably OK, but if you can I would avoid riding on it.

If it's caused by a broken spoke don't ride on it as you'll probably break more spokes.